# Cron или как выполнить скрипт в заданное время?

Tags: mysql, sql, highload

Есть проект где каждую минуту крон делает запрос в бд:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id_param = '153'
```

Достает допустим 10 строк, сравнивает время, если она в интервале текущего времени +/- 30 секунд, то выполняем какую-то работу.

Это все сильно грузит сервер, хотя запрос не сложный. 
Что можете подсказать, что бы не грузило сервер? как лучше реализовать это?

Если кто-то сталкивался, подскажите )

Comment: Покажите explain. 1 запрос в минуту с 10 строками - это ни о чём.

Comment: И если поле id_param числовое - уберите кавычки. А так же, раз вам нужены записи только +-30 секунд прямо в запросе такое условие задайте, что бы ничего лишнего из БД не тянуть